# Uploading files to an ownCloud server programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, socket.io, owncloud

I am trying to set a web application where many clients can connect through a Node.js http server and then upload/download files that will then be shown in different displays. I am thinking about having those files stored in a free cloud service that can be integrated to my app. Oh, and I am also using socket.IO in this project.

Dropbox offers some API to do this: https://www.dropbox.com/developers but I was looking into a free solution like ownCloud where I can have a larger amount of storage and also have my own private server.

Does anyone know if this can be done? or can offer any tips about alternative solutions to my problem? I would really appreciate any help with this since I am quite new to all this.

Answer (score 13):

@Javier Gonzalez, To upload a file...

Bad option:

```
curl -X PUT "http://yourserver.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/file.zip" -F myfile=@"/Users/Javi/Downloads/file.zip"
```

For, the uploaded file will contain the http headers.

Better option:

```
curl -X PUT "http://yourserver.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/file.zip" --data-binary @"/Users/Javi/Downloads/file.zip"
```

Or just use curl -T filename url to upload

Comment: HI, thanks do you have any idea how to create folder using API?

Comment: be sure to use a valid target url without whitespaces etc. or escape them. CURL is not doing it for you.

Comment: @TomasSykora you can create folders in ownclod by using curl and webdav. This is how to create a folder with current date as name:
curl -u user:pass -X MKCOL "http://example.org/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/$(date '+%d-%b-%Y')"    
see docs: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/user_manual/files/files.html#accessing-files-using-curl

Comment: @iGbanam How to upload $_files array ? if i upload from a form , i can not specify the path of uploading file.

Answer (score 9):

You have to communicate with the WebDav interface at http://yourowncloudserver.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/

To upload a file you have to make a PUT request to the destiny of the file for example:
http://yourowncloudserver.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/file.zip

And add the input stream to the request to read the file.

Here is the CURL command:

```
curl -X PUT -u username:password "http://yourserver.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/file.zip" -F myfile=@"/Users/Javi/Downloads/file.zip"
```

You also can check our code on Objective C to check the parameters that we use:
[ownCloud iOS Library](https://github.com/owncloud/ios-library/blob/master/OCCommunicationLib/OCCommunicationLib/OCWebDavClient/OCWebDAVClient.m)

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"PUT" path:remoteDestination parameters:nil];
[request setTimeoutInterval:k_timeout_upload];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", [UtilsFramework getSizeInBytesByPath:localSource]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
//[request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:localSource]];

__weak __block OCHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self mr_operationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];

[operation setInputStream:[NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:localSource]];
```

Comment: The better answer is listed below, as stated by @Frank Lu the uploaded file will be corrupt using this method of curl if it is not sent as binary data.

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to the existing answers, I use the following function as alias:

```
cloud() {
  curl -X PUT -u "<username>:<password>" "https://<hostname>/remote.php/webdav/${2:-$1}" --data-binary @"./$1"
}
```

Just replace `<username>`, `<password>` and `<hostname>` and put this in your .bash_aliases and you can upload your files with:

```
cloud filename
cloud path filename
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the webdav interface of owncloud

Answer (score 0):

Using curl for windows and owncloud 8. The only way I found to transfer a file  was by using this command

```
curl -u user:password --upload-file "c:\path to file\srcfile" "https://ocserver/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/tgtfile"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Upload a file** you have to make a *PUT* request to the destiny of the file for example: http://yourOwnCloudServer/remote.php/webdav/text.txt

Here is the CURL command:

```
curl -X PUT -u username:password "http://yourOwnCloudServer/remote.php/webdav/text.txt" -F myfile=@"/Users/gokul/Desktop/text.txt"
```

You can also use `--data-binary` for media files.

```
"http://yourOwnCloudServer/remote.php/webdav/image.jpg" --data-binary @"/Users/gokul/Desktop/image.jpg"
```