# Uploading Files to an owncloud using curl

Tags: linux, curl, console, owncloud

I have written an Application, should upload some files to several mobile devices. By now, I am using dropbox, I have an App (https://www.dropbox.com/developers), so I can upload any data to the clients Dropbox.

Now I would like to switch to owncloud because of some security concerns. I already have read this:
[Uploading files to an ownCloud server programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758167/uploading-files-to-an-owncloud-server-programatically)

But unfortunately it didn't help.

I tried

```
curl -X PUT -u username:password "http://myserver.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/test" -F f=@"/tmp/test"
```

The file was uploaded, but there was a Problem: Some kind of Header was added to my file.

Original test-file:

> test

Uploaded File:

> --------------------------00c5e21306fd0b2d Content-Disposition: form-data; name="f"; filename="test" Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream
>
> Dies ist ein Test.
>
> --------------------------00c5e21306fd0b2d--

While this is really annoying on any text-Files it is a desaster on any binary files like JPGs etc, because they can't be opened any more after uploading.

That's why, I tried the other possible way, which was described:

```
mischka@lappy:/tmp$ curl -X PUT -u 'username:password' "http://myserver/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/test" --data-binary @"/tmp/test"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:error xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://sabredav.org/ns">
  <s:exception>Sabre\DAV\Exception\BadRequest</s:exception>
  <s:message>expected filesize 19 got 0</s:message>
</d:error>
```

But the result was even worse!

Can anyone tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

`-F` means form upload, you should use `--data-binary` instead:

```
curl -X PUT -u username:password 
"http://myserver.com/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/test" --data-binary @"/tmp/test"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Upload a file** you have to make a *PUT* request to the destiny of the file for example:  http://yourOwnCloudServer/remote.php/webdav/text.txt

Here is the CURL command:

```
curl -X PUT -u username:password "https://yourOwnCloudServer/remote.php/webdav/text.txt" -F myfile=@"/Users/gokul/Desktop/text.txt"
```

You can also use `--data-binary` for media files.

```
"https://yourOwnCloudServer/remote.php/webdav/image.jpg" --data-binary @"/Users/gokul/Desktop/image.jpg"
```

Remember to use HTTPS or in most owncloud installations will reply

```
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://yourOwnCloudServer/remote.php/webdav/test">here</a>.</p>
```