# Display owncloud image in website

Tags: javascript, image, get, owncloud

I'm trying to build a service into my website to allow uploads to be saved to owncloud and then displayed.
As per this: [Uploading files to an ownCloud server programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758167/uploading-files-to-an-owncloud-server-programatically)
I was able to setup postman to upload files and successfully save to serve. Now how do I display those files or do a getrequest to display an image on my website?

Comment: You'd also need to either share that image with a link in a programmatic manner or you have to proxy the image via your http server to keep the credentials secret and handle session management. All in all owncloud is a horrible tool for this task. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found the get command. You need to make sure you have the authorization header as in postman for example.
You could do a **get** call

```
<baseurl>/owncloud/remote.php/<user>/<folder>/<pathtofile>
```

if you click on authorization select normal then put in your credentials it will generate a token key for you, this should be a separate call itself to generate a unique one each time.

You can also create folders to upload to using the **MKCOL** request. I had to export my postman and edit the export to have the **MKCOL** request b/c they are not built in.

```
<baseurl>/owncloud/remote.php/<user>/<foldertocreate>
```